# Functional Analysis In Measure Proof

Tags: functional-analysis

We are supposed to prove this statement:

Prove that if $u_n \in \mathcal{L}^1$ satisfies $\int_{\Omega} |u_n|~d\mu \rightarrow 0$, then $\{u_n\}$  converges to 0 in measure.

The definition we are given is as follows:

Let $u_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a positive measure space $\mathcal{M}(\Omega,\mu)$, let $u$ be also a measurable function. We say $\{u_n\}$ converges to $u$ in measure if for any $\epsilon>0, \mu(\{x\in\Omega | |u_n(x) - u(x)| \geq \epsilon\}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$.

It's obvious to me if $u_n \in \mathcal{L^1}$ and $\mathcal{L}^1 \subset M$, then $u_n \in M$. For the proof's sake though, I'm not really sure where to start.

Any help in getting me started on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Idea: If a sequence does not vanish in measure, then you can find an $\varepsilon>0$ and a $B>0$ so that the 1-norm is greater than $B\varepsilon$ for infinitely many sequents

Comment: The measure of a set is the integral of the corresponding indicator function. Integration is monoton.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus is right - a good way to prove this is to prove the contra-positive: If $u_n$ does not converge to $0$ in measure, then $\int |u_n| \not\to 0$.